# iphone push notification provider limit

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I want to install same push notification certificate in multiple servers. I wonder Is there any limitation for provider(server) count with same certificate?

For example, We have 10 clients who bought our web application server. The server has function that works as push notification provider for iphone users. There is iphone application on App Store that works client of web application. All servers uses same iphone application and same push notification certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install the certificate on multiple servers, there's no limitation as far as I know. The only recommendation is that you keep the connection with the Apple server open for as long as possible, and that you refrain to send notifications to devices where your application has been uninstalled. For this, you have to query [Apple's feedback service](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingWIthAPS/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html).